# Powerpoint: a slide that counts to 2010

Tags: animation, visual-effects, counter, microsoft-powerpoint

I want a slide in powerpoint that shows the number 0 and when I click a button the number increases by one one until 2010.

It should take 4 to 6 seconds. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You may need some VBA code to do that. This [thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/41101/Where-I-can-I-get-a-counter-thingy-for-a-powerpoint-slide) is about the same thing you ask, but may not answer 100% of your question. You can also ask this question on [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) to get VBA related answers.

Answer (score 1):

To do it in Powerpoint, you might need to make an animated .gif.  You could program a counter and capture a video of it with camstudio or the like.

Your ones digit will be a blur effect, because you want to display 600 numbers every second, or about 10 counts every frame.

Answer (score 1):

This [site](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00081.htm) offers several suggestions for creating the counter. Most are a variation on the theme of using a large stack of overlapping objects and animating them to appear one at a time. This could be tedious to create, so this [article](http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/Animated_Timer2.html) describes a VB macro that creates them for you.